# How can I write a _FillValue parameter in a NetCDF CHAR Variable using Java?

Tags: java, netcdf

I am trying to create a NetCDF file using java (unidata library). One of the requirements is to include the _FillValue attribute in all the Variables. I have one of type CHAR, and I can not do it.

The Attribute constructor only accepts Strings or numbers (or arrays of them), not chars. I have tried both of them anyway but the final netcdf does not show the attribute.

Other languages let you do it (we have seen this working in matlab), but I don't know how to do it using java.

I see in the documentation that the _FillValue should be of the same type of the Variable itself but Attribute values does not accept Chars, only String or Numbers

For example: When I try

```
    Nc4Chunking chunker = Nc4ChunkingStrategy.factory(Nc4Chunking.Strategy.standard, 6, true);
    NetcdfFileWriter dataFile = NetcdfFileWriter.createNew(NetcdfFileWriter.Version.netcdf4_classic, fileName, chunker);
....
    Variable varid_scdr = dataFile.addVariable(null, "SCDR", DataType.CHAR, dimsTMS15);
    varid_scdr.addAttribute(new Attribute("_FillValue", " "));
....
    dataFile.write(varid_scdr, scodData);
    dataFile.close();
```

The resulting netcdf file has no _FillValue, it is not written in the file.
But if I change the attribute name and do this

```
    varid_scdr.addAttribute(new Attribute("FillValue", " "));
```

the parameter is present in the output file

I have no problems with other data types or other attribute names. I am prety sure that the problem is about the attribute _FillValue for the variable of type Char. I dont know how to write it and I need the _FillValue attribute to be explicity present in the variable attribute list.

********* 5th July 2019 ***********

I realized that the problem is only related to netcdf4 and netcdf4_classic files. So perhaps is about chunking or something like that. If I try it creating netcdf3 files it workis.

Any help about this issue? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to bug that has been addressed in the latest version of netcdf-java (`v5.0.0`). [v5.0.0](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf-java/index.jsp) has been released and is available for download; my hope is that the announcement will go out today.

If you want to be explicit about writing a `CHAR` valued attribute, one way to to it would be:

```java
String fillValue = " ";
Array charArrayFillValue = ArrayChar.makeFromString(fillValue, 1);
charAttrFillValue = new Attribute("_FillValue", charArrayFillValue);
varid_scdr.addAttribute(charAttrFillValue)
```

another way would be:

```java
String fillValue = " ";
Array charArrayFillValue = ArrayChar.makeFromString(fillValue, 1);
charAttrFillValue = new Attribute("_FillValue", DataType.CHAR);
charAttrFillValue.setValues(charArrayFillValue);
varid_scdr.addAttribute(charAttrFillValue)
```

Both of those are a bit verbose, though. I just checked using version 5, and your one liner works:

```
varid_scdr.addAttribute(new Attribute("_FillValue", " "));
```

However, if you try to pass in a value for `_FillValue` that isn't a string of length 1, the netCDF-C library will throw an error. So this:

```
varid_scdr.addAttribute(new Attribute("_FillValue", "ab"));
```

will result in:

```
-36 (NetCDF: Invalid argument) on attribute ':_FillValue = "ab"' on var varid_scdr
```

netCDF-Java will make sure the string you pass in gets converted to `CHAR`s, but it won't truncate the resulting set of `CHAR`s to fit into the single character limit on the `_FillValue` attribute.

Comment: YES!Thank you Sean, I tried the version 5 and it works now. I have now to update some part of my code as it looks like it is not completely retrocompatible but this is a very good new for me.